# Why finding the device location takes more than 10-15 seconds?

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I have implemented the `LocationManager`, I have set an `listener` on the location change but when I need the position, it take more than 10-15sec to give me the (first) position.

I have tried on differents terminal but it took approximately the same time.

```java
private void gestionGPS() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return;
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    String fourniseur = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Log.d("GPS wola", "fourniseur " + fourniseur);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocationListener);
}

private final LocationListener myLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Récupération des valeurs
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        // Gestion affichage
        txtLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
        txtLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
        // On coupe le listener
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager = null;
    }
}
```

I want to know if it is a hardware limitation?
I want to know if Google location service is faster because I use the intern one.
Are they any trick to make "feels" it faster?

**UPDATE**

> I tried with the same code on an old Android (Android 4.2), it seems faster but I guess it the think that the position is inside a house.

Comment: Device hardware is a factor that affects the speed . Also sometimes if you are inside a building it might take more time to retrieve a location. But usually 10-15 seconds is too long to retrieve a location.

Comment: It is the fault of the code then ?

Comment: try using google location services and compare the differences between times

Comment: I will test thanks !

Comment: I don't think 15 seconds for the first GPS location is weird at all.